# Como paso la propiedad de un objeto, seleccionado en un formulario

Tags: angular, angular-material

Tengo un arreglo con 3 objetos y este a su vez, tiene 3 propiedades en donde estoy iterando en un mat-option de angular, pero solo logro pasar un atributo y en el componente sé como acceder al campo, pero no logro pasar las propiedades del objeto según la selección que haga el usuario.

Componente.ts

```
productos = [
    {name: "eggs", value: 1, prefix: "EGS"}
    {name: "beans", value: 3, prefix: "BNS"}
    {name: "rice", value: 5, prefix: "RCE" }
]

fields() {
   this.liteFormgroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   nameofProduct: ['', Validators.required],
   prefix: ['']
   })   
}

Html

.......="ngForm" [formGroup]="liteFormGroup"
  <mat-select placeholder="Name of producst" formControlName="nameofProduct" name="nameofProduct" id="nameofProduct">
    <mat-option *ngFor= let producto of productos [value]="producto.value id="{{producto.value}}">
        {{producto.name}}
    <mat-option>
```

Yo quiero, que cuando el usuario seleccione por ejemplo "eggs", tambien se pase la propiedad "prefix", osea "EGS", en el body de la petición y que ahorita solo pasa en blanco, agradecido con sus comentarios.

Comment: porque no envias el `producto`  y en el service le extraes lo que necesitas enviar al servicio.

Answer (score 0):

La forma que encuentro más fácil para solucionar el problema es utilizando la directiva `compareWith`. Puedes leer más sobre ella [acá](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection). Es una directiva que se encarga de encontrar el objeto seleccionado usando la función que le pasamos para que haga la comparación y lo encuentre.

Puedes hacer uso de ella de la siguiente forma:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="seleccionado" [compareWith]="compareWith">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let producto of productos" [value]="producto">
        {{ producto.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```
  public form: FormGroup;

  public productos = [
    { name: "eggs", value: 1, prefix: "EGS" },
    { name: "beans", value: 3, prefix: "BNS" },
    { name: "rice", value: 5, prefix: "RCE" }
  ];

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      seleccionado: ['']
    })    
  }

  public compareWith(object1: Producto, object2: Producto) {
    return object1 && object2 && object1.prefix === object2.prefix;
  }
```

En vez de guardar el prefix en otra propiedad del form, se almacena el objeto completo en la propiedad `seleccionado` en el formGroup.

Cree un ejemplo [acá](https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-369573)